# Why Doesn't FDT Start ADL Or Show Anything When I Launch?

Tags: flash, air, fdt

When I launch a simple AIR project. ADL doesn't start / or I dont' see anything:

```
Starting Full Build of Application.
Compiler arguments:
  -output 
    C:\Dev\FDT5\fdt_workspace\Application\bin\Application.swf
  -+configname=air +flexlib=
    C:\Dev\flex_sdk_4.6\frameworks
  --compiler.debug=false
  --debug-password=
  --compiler.source-path+=
    C:\Dev\FDT5\fdt_workspace\Application\src
  --compiler.library-path+=
    C:\Dev\flex_sdk_4.6\frameworks\libs\air\airglobal.swc,
    C:\Dev\flex_sdk_4.6\frameworks\libs\textLayout.swc,
    C:\Dev\flex_sdk_4.6\frameworks\libs\osmf.swc,
    C:\Dev\flex_sdk_4.6\frameworks\libs\authoringsupport.swc,
    C:\Dev\flex_sdk_4.6\frameworks\libs\core.swc,
    C:\Dev\flex_sdk_4.6\frameworks\libs\air\aircore.swc,
    C:\Dev\flex_sdk_4.6\frameworks\libs\air\applicationupdater.swc,
    C:\Dev\flex_sdk_4.6\frameworks\libs\air\applicationupdater_ui.swc,
    C:\Dev\flex_sdk_4.6\frameworks\libs\air\servicemonitor.swc
  -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=
    true
  -target-player=11.1
  -library-path+=
    C:\Dev\flex_sdk_4.6/frameworks/locale/en_US
  -default-size=550,400
  -- 
 C:\Dev\FDT5\fdt_workspace\Application\src\com\powerflasher\SampleApp\Application.as

INFO Loading configuration file C:\Dev\flex_sdk_4.6\frameworks\air-config.xml

Pure build time: 265 ms. 
Save compiler information in 6 ms. 
Clean compiler information in 0 ms. 
828 bytes written to file C:\Dev\FDT5\fdt_workspace\Application\bin\Application.swf
in 273 ms

Launching AIR Debug Launcher
C:\Dev\flex_sdk_4.6\bin\adl.exe
    -nodebug
    -profile
    desktop
    C:\Dev\FDT5\fdt_workspace\Application\bin\Application-app.xml
    C:\Dev\FDT5\fdt_workspace\Application\bin
```

I don't see anything.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your permissions are correct ( you can execute files within the Flex SDK ) and ADL is in fact launching (check this by using your operating system's process viewer), the most likely solution is that the `<visible>` property in your description.xml is not set or set to false.

Change it to true:

```
<visible>true</visible>
```

Later versions of FDT will have the ability to toggle this as a GUI option.

Comment: +1 . Thank You.
But, I don't understand, why it's "false" by default ?  It may be required in a special case. But normally, i think, everyone would like to see the initial window. Took me a long time, unless I figured out with this post.